# Google Map api added span(BESbewy) at page load, why??

Tags: google-maps

Google map api added a span using some specific word with some css style that will break my page content in mobile site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally in google maps Api "BESBEWY" occurs at the end of span, on that span some CSS id applied, try this:

```
$('body > span').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === 'BESbewy') {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using jQuery and loops you could use XPath to get the element ( and then check if it is exist obviously):

```
var unwantedSpan = document.evaluate(
    '//body/span[text()="BESbswy"]', document, 
    null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null
).singleNodeValue
```

Or if all you care is Chrome browser you could just use

```
var unwantedSpan = $('//body/span[text()="BESbswy"]')
```

This span is added in mobile only and done by google maps for calculations purposes.